# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI Spring

Tags: spring

I am new to Spring. I have created a project using Spring 4.1 but unfortunately my http mapping not working with Dispatcher. Here is the code for my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Disptcher Servelet xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd">

<bean name="./hello.htm" class="com.practice.controller.HelloController" />

</beans>
```

Controller code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.practice.controller;

/**
 *
 * @author david
 */

import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloController implements Controller {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloController.class);

    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        logger.info("Returning hello view");

        return new ModelAndView("hello.jsp");
    }



}
```

Unfortunately system is unable to map my request to controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below line along with the controller declaration. It makes sure to scan all the controller and define the URL mappings after stripping of the string "controller" from the controller name.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
```

**Note:** The Spring MVC configuration that you are following is pretty old. I would suggest to use the latest version of spring. It using `@Controller` to define a controller and `@RequestMapping` to define a URL mappings.